# Using GPX route or track for testing in Xcode 4.2

Tags: iphone, ios, core-location, xcode4.2

Has anyone had any success using a GPX route or track to test location aware apps that depend on movement in Xcode 4.2? I have been able to get it to use a single waypoint in a GPX file or even get it to iterate over a series of waypoints, but I have not been able to have it follow a track in a way that would give speed and course information. I have tried with recorded tracks from driving, hand made routes and tracks, and routes made with Trailrunner.

It may be that this functionality just is not available, but Apple does provide a freeway drive in the simulator. I want to be able to do something similar on device and in a location that I can specify. Anybody have any thoughts?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is speed and course information. If I got you right, you already got it going the way that was shown in the WWDC Developer Tools Kickoff Video (17:44)? This works fine for me with a recorded route (e.g. downloaded from everytrial.com). Which freeway drive are you referring to?

Comment: There is a menu in the simulator itself that lets you choose from some predefined tracks that Apple has provided. The speed and course information is what I want. It shows up when using the predefined tracks in the simulator, but if I use my own tracks it will not work on the device or the simulator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to create your own simulator class to read the file and generate CLLocation events, which gives you complete control. GPX files don't contain speed and heading, so you'll have to calculate them yourself. The basic simulation loop I've used is:

```
Simulate{
  if (!eof) {
    Read the next waypoint
    Calculate distance, dt (delta time), bearing and speed (distance/dt) from the previous waypoint

    Generate a CLLocation object and call the didUpdateToLocation delegate method
    Peek at the next waypoint and calculate next_dt
    Scale next_dt   // as desired for faster playback (e.g. dt/2 would be 2x)
    Start an NSTimer with next_dt as the duration
  }
}

When the timer fires, call Simulate again
```

Note: Until recently, synthesizing CLLocations was somewhat problematic since CLLocation is immutable and the init method had no way to set speed and heading. This was remedied in iOS 4.2.

Comment: I thought perhaps speed and heading were supported in a GPX extension, but the only ones I've found (from Garmin and Humminbird) do not. If someone knows differently, I'll stand corrected.

Comment: This does seem to be the only way of getting it to happen on the device itself. The GPX format does allow for course and speed tags, but as you observed, they are not always recorded by the GPS. Some apps will record this info, though. For the simulator I think a similar method could be used to generate the simulation file as discussed by Steve Madsen.

Answer (score 4):

The Freeway Drive appears to be defined by a 1.6 MB file in `/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/Support/SimulationScenarios/Freeway Drive.plist`. It's a dictionary with two keys, `Options` and `Locations`. `Options` itself is a dictionary with two keys and can probably be reverse engineered. `Locations`, on the other hand, is a large array (2240 items) of `NSData`, each one about 724 bytes. The first eight bytes decode to "bplist00", so each of these is a plist. I wrote one to disk, but Xcode's property list editor claims it is corrupted.

The directory where that file is is also where the other canned locations and routes live. I duplicated one of the files and restarted the simulator, and the new file showed up in the Debug menu.

The biggest issue with adding your own files is that a future Xcode update might erase them, but that's not such a big deal if you keep the originals somewhere.

Comment: I hadn't discovered this yet. It looks like each of those bplist00 lines is an archive of a CLLocation object. I could probably write a tool to generate a similar file from a GPX track, but it would only be available on the simulator. I would really like to be able to do this on the device.

Comment: I doubt Apple will offer a way to simulate location changes on the device since it natively supports location determination through some combination of Wi-Fi, cell towers and GPS. You'll need to roll your own code to fake location updates there.

Comment: Apple does support single locations and cycling through a series of points in a gpx file on the device. There just doesn't seem to be support for moving data with course and speed.

Comment: That sounds very interesting. Do you have a link?

Comment: Do I have a link to what? I've put gpx files into the project (recorded, generated, and hand-made versions). The location button on the debugger lets you select the file to use to simulate location. It will only use waypoints, not trackpoints. If you provide a list of waypoints, it will visit each one in order. I have not been able to get it to use any speed or course info that is attached to the waypoints.

Comment: I meant a link to how to simulate alternate locations when running on the device, but your explanation is good. I wasn't aware the location button in the debugger could stand in for the real location hardware on the device.

Answer (score 1):

You can plot complex routes using Google Maps and then convert them to a compatible GPX file using https://mapstogpx.com/mobiledev.php

Comment: It wants me to paste my API key.